# 301 redirect subfolder without allowing subdirectories to redirect with same rule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have set up the 301 redirect below which will redirect /jobs and all subpages below it when a user navigates to

https://www.main-domain.com/jobs/

```
 RedirectMatch 301 /jobs/.* https://www.main-domain.com/all-vacancies/
```

My issue arises as I have a sub-site in a subdirectory on "main-domain.com" which also uses the path /jobs which is being redirected when I want it excluded e.g.

```
 https://www.main-domain.com/subsite/jobs/
 # I don't want this url redirected back to https://www.main-domain.com/all-vacancies/
```

I have tried the below to keep the /jobs to only redirect from the root of the domain but it did not work and I am stumped!

```
 RedirectMatch 301 ^(?i)/jobs/.*?$ https://www.main-domain.com/all-vacancies/
```

Cheers, JB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already match any request contains `/jobs/` by your code but to achieve what you want , to only match request starts with jobs , you should do the following  :

```
RedirectMatch 302 ^/jobs/.* https://www.main-domain.com/all-vacancies/
```

And also here this `.*` will not match any thong in new location and every request will be redirected to all-vacancies main page (`index`) but if you want any request to come as it is to all-vacancies change it to :

```
RedirectMatch 302 ^/jobs/(.*) https://www.main-domain.com/all-vacancies/$1
```

**Note :**   , clear your browser cache and test it .if Ok , change `302` to `301`

Comment: Just what I needed! Thanks